# Highcharts svg element "highcharts-series-group" not resizing

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working with charts that must resize dynamically. On calling the chart.setSize(containerWidth, containerHeight, boolean) method everything seems to resize appropriately except the svg element "highcharts-series-group". This element seems to remain fixed at the size that it had when the chart was created. The end result is that the parts of the graph that are outside of its "view box" are hidden.

Below are two images showing demonstrating this:

1: I minimized the screen for the initial creation of the chart
[image]

2: In the second image I have fully expended the browser further and applied the chart.resize() method which seems to work except as the image shows the "highcharts-series-group" svg element of the graph has not changed with this resulting in most of the group being hidden as it resizes beyond the "highcharts-series-group" boundaries. 
[image]

Am I missing something?

**EXTRA INFO:**
The only work around I have managed right now for this is to destroy the chart and to recreate it whenever the window resize event is triggered.

This would be all good except this gives a bad user experience as the chart "blinks" when it is destroyed and then created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the version. My organization was using version 2.0.2. Just updated to the latest (5.0.5) and the issue vanishes.